# Unique date with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have column defined as timestamp and called date. There are a bunch of other columns. I am having a network issue where i am getting the same packet twice in my code and thus my code writes it twice. So I get two of the exact same record.

```
date    timestamp       on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP       ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

After spending many days trying to solve this network issue, I am ready to work around that issue (for now). I am using the following Codeigniter code to insert the records.

```
$this->db->insert('survey_tasks', $data);          
$this->db->insert('survey_bc', $data2);
```

I have thought about using insert into 'where not exists' like the sample below but the issue is that the timestamp is being inserted automatically. That plus I don't know how to create a "complex" insert into in Codeigniter.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
  (id, name)
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.name
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id
                    FROM TABLE_2 t2
                   WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
```

So how can I require every record to have a unique time stamp?

Comment: Richard: Please stop adding demos for your code.  Stack Overflow does not support demo functionality for the code you posted here.

Comment: “So how can I require every record to have a unique time stamp?” You could try adding [6 fractional seconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html)

Comment: Tim, I am not sure what you mean? That "demo" was part of the answer to a similair Stack Overflow question, but with slightly different requirements. What part of me trying to explain the issue is troubling for you?

Comment: Raymond, the problem is not that the two inserts have a slightly different time stamp. They are actually the same request. They just appear twice. The fact that when rounded to the nearest sec they have the same time, helps me delete (or not insert!) one of them.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on the meta site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378272/is-there-anything-wrong-with-sharing-a-similair-response-in-my-question)